# C int data types *in practice*

Tags: c

The spec is obviously vague to the point of being almost useless, but my understanding is that *in practice* the integer types are always as follows:

- `int` - 16 bit on ancient 16 bit systems, otherwise always 32 bits even on 64 bit architectures
- `long` - always 32 bits
- `long long` - always 64 bits
- `size_t` - 32 bit on 32 bit systems, 64 bits on 64 bit systems (unsigned)

Is that table really correct?  Are there any significant implementations that violate it?

Updated Table based on responses below

- `int` - 16 bit on ancient 16 bit systems, otherwise always 32 bits even on 64 bit architectures
- `long` - may be 32 or 64 bit on 64 bit systems.  (Windows 32, *nix usually 64)
- `long long` - always 64 bits
- `size_t` - 32 bit on 32 bit systems, 64 bits on 64 bit systems (unsigned)

Comment: google "ILP64" for examples of systems where `int` is 64-bit, and "LP64" for more examples of systems where `long` is 64-bit.

Comment: Saying that `long` is always 32 bits is the most likely of your assumptions to be false.  It's untrue on most modern systems other than Windows.

Comment: That's why you should use fixed width integer types, when the specific size matters: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

Comment: I've seen `int` and `long` in range from 16-bit to 64-bit, but I'm sure there are even more exotic systems. If size is important for you, use types with defined size, like `int16_t` etc. if your compiler supports them. Otherwise, `#define` your own and assert that their `sizeof` is what you expect.

Comment: Anything vaguely unixy, like Linux, MacOS, *BSD, Solaris, HPUX, etc. are LP64 on 64 bit machines, so their `long` is 64 bits. Only Windows uses the  IL32P64 model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> long - always 32 bits

That's wrong assumption. There are platforms with 64-bit `long`
I think you can begin from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types)